# Thin client pxe booting into terminal server and WDS conflicting

Tags: windows-server-2008

We have got a WDS running in our environment. Now we are in a process of implementing diskless workstation which will pxe boot into the Windows Terminal Server (2008R2) using a third party tool. But now the problem is both these services are conflicting. So when I press F12 button it is booting from the Terminal Server not from the WDS. I need both the services to be working. How do I achieve this?

--
Tony

Comment: How about a menu that lets you select from both options during boot (potentially defaulting to one or the other after a set timeout)?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That's a wonderful option. This link http://deployvista.com/Home/tabid/36/EntryID/99/language/en-US/Default.aspx helped me to get a menu of WDS server. But how do I list out Terminal server on the same menu. We are using 'thinstation.nbi.zpxe' file in DHCP for thin clients to boot into terminal server.

-- Tony